# Springboot and Swagger UI 500 error Schema.requiredMode()'

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I am trying to connect my Spring Boot to Swagger UI. I am using this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
     <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to access Swagger UI through /swagger-ui/index.html I get a 500 error:

[image]

The current configuration in `application.yaml` I have:

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: "/api-docs"
```

Config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;

@OpenAPIDefinition
@Configuration
public class SpringdocConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI baseOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("Dashboard API").version("1.0.0").description("Dashboard API"));
    }

}
```

Error:

```
2023-07-04T11:15:18.312+02:00 DEBUG 33532 --- [-nio-443-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema$RequiredMode io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.requiredMode()'
2023-07-04T11:15:18.313+02:00 ERROR 33532 --- [-nio-443-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema$RequiredMode io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.requiredMode()'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema$RequiredMode io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema.requiredMode()'
        at org.springdoc.core.configuration.SpringDocRequiredModule$RespectSchemaRequiredAnnotationIntrospector.hasRequiredMarker(SpringDocRequiredModule.java:52) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.hasRequiredMarker(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]    
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getMetadata(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:230) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._anyIndexed(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:1240) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
```

I expect to see the endpoints of my controllers in Swagger UI.

Comment: Have to create a class for swagger configuration?

Comment: yes i created a class but i think as it says in the doc it's not mandatory

Comment: What is the version of Spring boot you are using ?

Comment: I am using 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating to spring 3.

I added this dependency to the openapi-starter:

```
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0"
implementation "io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.15"
```

Hope this is working for you.